# How to add icons to the launcher on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: launcher, ubuntu-touch

I would like to add an icon for Terminal and a couple of icons
for my own scripts to the launcher on my Ubuntu Touch. How can I
do that?

Answer (score 4):

In recent builds, when you launch an app from the dash it's icon will appear in the Launcher while it is running.  You can then long-press on it's icon to get a menu which has an option to "Pin to Launcher".